# why is a Double Leading Underscore method in a python class assigned to a Single Leading Underscore variable

Tags: python

I see in a python class following pattern

```
class xxx(object):

    def __some_method():
        pass

    _some_method = __some_method
```

why would somebody use this pattern of assigning the Double Leading Underscore method to a Single Leading Underscore variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of a single and a double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Comment: Would it mean i can override the function by changing the private variable

Comment: Ultimately you would have to ask the author of this code what *exactly* their intention was behind this.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense at all